# GRASS init error when opening QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, error

This error has prevailed through many installations and now is about time to get rid of it.

I get the following error message each time I open QGIS. I only install stable versions of QGIS. (No nightlies)

> GRASS init error: Problem in GRASS initialization, GRASS provider and
> plugin will not work : Module built against version
> 2021-02-10T17:13:06+00:00 but trying to use version
> 2021-02-10T17:08:53+00:00. You need to rebuild GRASS GIS or untangle
> multiple installations.

Looks like there is a discrepancy in the clocks?

I have seen the old questions but they did not have any useful answers.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What OS ? How did you install QGIS and GRASS? What versions ?

Comment: MacOS, latest version. I have had QGIS and GRASS installed many years. The first would be from the time when they had separate installers from kyngchaos(?). I keep QGIS updated with the latest stable releases. Using the official installer.

Comment: I don't use MacOS, so I can't make any specific suggestions, but you might have a mismatch in versions from different installers.

Comment: I have the same issue.  QGIS 3.16, MacOS 11.4.         Clean install.